# Python nltk classify with large feature set (Replicate Go Et Al 2009)

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to replicate Go Et Al. Twitter sentiment Analysis which can be found here http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students
The problem I'm having is the number of features is 364464. I'm currently using nltk and nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier to do this where tweets holds a replication of the 1,600,000 tweets and there polarity:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet[0] = extract_features(tweet[0], features)

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
# print "NB Classified"
classifier.show_most_informative_features()
print(nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testdata))
```

Everything doesn't take very long apart from the extract_features function

```
def extract_features(tweet, featureList):
  tweet_words = set(tweet)
  features = {}
  for word in featureList:
      features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in tweet_words)
  return features
```

This is because for each tweet it's creating a dictionary of size 364,464 to represent whether something is present or not.

Is there a way to make this faster or more efficient without reducing the number of features like in this paper?

Comment: I wonder why don't you want to use the same techniques as in the paper. Anyway, basic NLP steps you could take include: removing stopwords, do a tfidf vectorization and remove less common or very common words... Those would remove features also, but just in a different way. As I said, I'm not really sure what you want to do.

Comment: I was running into memory issues as you can imagine, but I managed to solve it. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a wonderful function called:
nltk.classify.util.apply_features()
which you can find herehttp://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html

```
    training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(extract_features, tweets)
```

I had to change my extract_features function but it now works with the huge sizes without memory issues.

Here's a lowdown of the function description:

> The primary purpose of this function is to avoid the memory overhead involved in storing all the featuresets for every token in a corpus. Instead, these featuresets are constructed lazily, as-needed. The reduction in memory overhead can be especially significant when the underlying list of tokens is itself lazy (as is the case with many corpus readers).

and my changed function:

```
    def extract_features(tweet):
         tweet_words = set(tweet)
         global featureList
         features = {}
         for word in featureList:
            features[word] = False
         for word in tweet_words:
            if word in featureList:
                features[word] = True
         return features
```